# Create new view at "Admin Dashboard" Template from ExtJs 6

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I'm starting with ExtJs 6 .

I installed the "Admin Dashboard" template in my application and now I'm having trouble creating a new menu item and see it opens up.

Which are the steps that I need to add this item without build the application and avoid "[Ext.create] Unrecognized class name / alias: widget. [...]" error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, ExtJS has a pretty long learning curve, it also has a pretty good documentation and tutorials. You should really check out the [Core Concepts](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/guides/core_concepts/classes.html), [Architecture](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/guides/application_architecture/application_architecture.html) and the [Tutorial](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/guides/tutorials/login_app.html)

Putting that aside, you are seeing the `[Ext.create] Unrecognized class name / alias: widget. [...]` error, because Ext can't find the class you want to create.

Every time you want to create a class using `Ext.create("MY_APP.view.MY_CLASS")` you should make sure that the javascript file containing `MY_APP.view.MY_CLASS` actually gets loaded.

Usually you can use requires in your `Application.js` or `view/Main.js` to load the js file

```
Ext.define('MY_APP.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    requires: ['MY_APP.view.MY_CLASS'],
    xtype: 'mainView'
});
```

Please note, that `MY_APP.view.Main` actually translates to ExtJS folder structure meaning that `MY_APP.view.Main` class should be defined in `app/view/Main.js` (this is the file ExtJS will try to load when using `requires: ["MY_APP.view.Main"]`)

And again, you should really check out [ExtJS docs and guides](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/)

Comment: Hi Gašper. First of all, thanks for your great answer. I had worked with Ext Js 4 and now I starting with Ext Js 6. I read these tutorials and also know that the "loading archtecture" exists. In ExtJs 4 I think it is quite simple, but the strucute is direferent in Extjs 6. Also, my problem is specific with "Admin Dashboard" template provided by sencha. I created my view model at app/view/MyViewFolder/viewmodel.js and my view as app/classic/src/MyViewFolder/view.js and in app.js I put "requires: ['MyApp.*']". But I still getting this error. Could you help me?

Comment: I never actually got `requires: ['MyApp.*']` to work in ExtJS6. I always use full name of the class. Strangely, `requires: ['Ext.*']` works.

Comment: I tried to put the full name and I am getting the cutom 404 fault of "Admin Dashboard" template. It is really strange.

Comment: Strange, are you sure, that your view gets loaded? Do you see it load in the Network tab of developer tools?

Comment: It is not loaded. But the "Admin Dashboard" template have example pages using ['Admin.*'] and they loads as well. But, my new pages, following the same example, are not working.

Comment: I just tried adding a class to the Admin template, under Admin namespace (`Admin.view.profile.Test`), and it loads only if I require it with a full name. Maybe it's a sencha cmd bug?

Comment: I looked Ext.manifest.classes and all "Admin" namespaces was found. Except my new classes. Do you have any idea how it can happens?

Comment: I found out what was going on. The problem is that in Extjs 6 dependencies are mapped in the manifest file (classic.json and modern.json) . In "Admin Panel " references to the classes are stored within this document as well. So, I put the reference in the manifest file and it solved my problem. Thanks Gašper

Comment: The manifest file should be updated automatically if you run `sencha app refresh` - see http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/guides/extjs/cmd_app.html

Comment: Thanks again, Gašper. I runned this command, but did not update the manisfest. Maybe my Sencha cmd has a bug

Answer (score 1):

Presuming the normal AdminDashboard navigation tree based menu system and it's MainController "hash token to route" based view creation scheme, I was successful with the following:

- Make sure that app sources are directly accessible from your web application context root.
- At least once after generating the app from the template, recompile with 'sencha app build development' from the app home directory.
- Add the view class to the system with it's respective xtype (used as the xtype widget alias, this needs to match the app url hash token for the navigation route). Note @Gasper's answer about folder setup.
- You can either explicitly require the class, or update the bootstrap loader with 'sencha app refresh', which makes the app's bootstrap system aware of the classes and their aliases and alternates.
- Note that the admin-dashboard mainControlller also tries to find a node in the NavigationTree store with a matching 'routeId' or 'viewType' attribute. If the lookup fails, you get the '404' view, so you need to either short-circuit this logic, or make sure that your new view's xtype has a matching viewType or routeId in the NavigationTree store.
- Now a page refresh for with a hash token matching your component's xtype should load the component into the main view.